# How to extract characters from a string in C?

Tags: c, string, char

I am interfacing with GSM SIM900 module which respond with `\r\n`. I have stored the GSM response in an array and need to extract characters from it. I m checking the response in docklight and it is like this:

```
\r\n +CMTI: "SM",1 \r\n
```

I need to extract last integer 1 from above and store it in a variable.
Here `\r\n` is carriage return and line feed
I am confused that whether `\r` (carriage return) should be considered as single or double char.

**Code:**

```
char var[15] = "\r\nhello:4";
int i,l;
char k;
for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
{
  if(isdigit(var[i]))
  {
    k = var[i];
    /* l = atoi(k);  */ 
    l = atoi(&var[i]); /* Get number from string */
    printf("output=%d",k);        
    printf("done");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("NO");
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by GSM or "it is like this". What's the actual string?

Comment: Why don't you use a loop to check each character whether it is a digit or not? There is a function which returns 1 when the character is a number.

Comment: which function, can you pls tell me

Comment: you need to know where the integer is or how to find it

Comment: @Giorgi I need to extract the integer

Comment: yes, but where is it? is it always at position 6? then you could just return stringArray[6] (assuming it is one digit). Otherwise you might need to parse it using `strtok` etc.

Comment: I am still not sure what you want. Do you need to extract every integer?

Comment: @jungyh0218 I need to extract and save it in another variable.

Comment: @Giorgi yes position is fix,

Comment: Is the string guaranteed that it contains only one integer???

Comment: I am confused that whether \r(carriage return should be considered as single or double char)

Comment: `\r\n` is standard DOS/Windows line endings and consists of 2 characters, the `\r` carriage return and the `\n` line feed.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck you mean to say \r is one character and \n is one character. If i include it in if condition then it should be like this if( data == '\r') or something else

Comment: Yes, if `data` is a `char` or `int`, then your `if` is correct.

Comment: Thanks @KlasLindbäck Now I am using isdigit function and converting char to int then, i have attached my code, it is giving me segmentation fault

Comment: The  call to `atoi` wasn't correct. `atoi` expects a string. See the change I made in your code.

Comment: If you print out k with "%d", then the ascii code value will be printed, instead of what you expected. you have to print out l, not k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two conditions make this problem very easy... the position is fixed and the string contains only one integer. There are various good ways but I think this will be the easiest one.

1. declare a character array.
2. start a loop from the starting point.
3. use isdigit() to check whether it is number or not.
4. if it is a number then add it into the array we declared.
5. After the loop is finished then add null character at the end of the array because it is a cstring.
6. convert it into an integer, with atoi function.

I am not sure that these functions are in standard library. But it will be easier to implement then using strtok function.

Comment: Hey thanks for this new isdigit function. It is really helpful. I am following your steps and getting the ouput but when I convert it into int, it is giving me segmentation fault. I have attached my code. Please have a look.

Comment: segmentation fault occurs when you access to a wrong place of memory. I guess this occurred because the length of the string is 9, but the for statement loop runs 11 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtok()` and `atoi()`, if you know the quoted portions won't contain commas.

Comment: `strrchr(data, ',')` can be used to find the last comma.